# Can't use a Directive Controller AND Require a Directive Controller (and have them both be available)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controllers

So I have a validation directive that should work with ng-form. I need to use their controller but also I need to bind the elements `click event` to my own controller. If I just use `require` I can access that form controller, if I just use `controller` I can access my controller, but if I use both `require` and `controller` I only get access to the required controller!

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('myValidation', function() {
    return {
      controller: function MyController() {

      },
      link: function($scope, ele, attr, MyCtrl) {
        // All is well
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myValidationTwo', function() {
    return {
      require: 'form',
      controller: function MyController() {

      },
      link: function($scope, ele, attr, formCtrl) {
        // MyCtrl is not available!
        // formCtrl is not an array of controllers!
      }
    };
  });
```

Seems like a major oversight if this isn't possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to require it specifically.

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('myValidation', function() {
    return {
      controller: function MyController() {

      },
      link: function($scope, ele, attr, MyCtrl) {
        // All is well
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('myValidationTwo', function() {
    return {
      require: ['myValidationTwo', 'form'],
      controller: function MyController() {

      },
      link: function($scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
        var MyCtrl = ctrl[0];
        var formCtrl = ctrl[1];
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: I tried so many variations. I did not try the actual name of the directive. Thanks!